# Is it possible to import shortcuts with a mobileconfig file?

Tags: shortcut, sirishortcuts, ios-shortcut, mobile-config

I wanted to import multiple shortcuts with one file. My idea was to make something like a shortcuts library/module where every shortcut is a function that can be runned by an other shortcut. Could a mobileconfig file be a solution?